# Eclipse mylyn redmine integration

Tags: eclipse, redmine, mylyn

Has anyone got the mylyn connector for redmine on eclipse working?

I'm keen to get this to work but have not been successful.

I'm on

- Eclipse Kepler SR1
- Redmine version                2.3.3.stable,
- Ruby version              1.9.3-p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails version                  3.2.13

Not so keen to use the generic web connector - looks like q lot of work to get it to work.

Comment: Have you installed http://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/ ? And if so, what version?

Comment: I've tried that version - 0.3.7 as well as the "later" versions on the other github sites, does that version work for you?

Comment: 2.7.5.stable works for me https://github.com/ljader/redmine-mylyn-connector on Redmine 1.2.0.stable.338 (OracleEnhanced)